# Numpy: specify axis order when creating RGB image array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 3 numpy arrays: R, G, B, each of shape (32, 32).

Now I want to make these into an image. I did

```
img = np.array([R, G, B])
```

However, if I do

```
img.shape
```

I get (3, 32, 32). I tried specifying the "order" parameter of the np.array function but all possibilities resulted in the same thing. What's the correct way? I don't want to use

```
np.swapaxes()
```

I'd prefer to build it the right way from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to stack arrays by the third axis:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> R = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
>>> G = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
>>> B = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
>>> np.dstack([R,G,B])
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]]])
>>> np.dstack([R,G,B]).shape
(2, 2, 3)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Each [i][j][k] element in the 3D array shows up as being transposed, and when the 3D array is plotted, the wrong color appears.

Answer (score 1):

Call `stack` along the last axis (effectively `dstack`)

```
img = np.stack([R, G, B], axis=-1)
img.shape
(32, 32, 3)
```